# Portfolio Projection

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to understand an Online Portfolio Selection Algorithm (AKA OPS, which are algorithms that update the portfolio when new data arrives), named local adaptive learning system (LOAD), that has been introduced by [Guna and An (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.knosys.2019.104958).
The image of the algorithm is provided below.
[image]

I do not understand the **14th line** of the algorithm. I do not know how to achieve the $\textbf{b}$ vector (if it is a vector (?)) and what's the meaning of $\arg \mathop {\min }\limits_{\textbf{b} \in {\Delta _m}} {\left\| {\textbf{b} - {\textbf{b}_{t + 1}}} \right\|^2}$. I'm not sure if they mean $\textbf{b}$ is a collection of portfolios and they want to find the one that has the lowest Euclidean distance from $\textbf{b}_{t + 1}$. Also, I don't know what they mean by projection.

P.S.: The meaning of $\Delta _m$ is:
$$1^T\textbf{b}_{t + 1} = 1$$
$${\textbf{b}_{t + 1}} \ge 0$$
This means, the weight of each asset in the portfolio should be between 0 and 1, and sum of the weights should be equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\hat{\mathbf b}_{t+1}$ on line 13 might not satisfy the constraints that define $\Delta_m$.  Line 14 is intended to find the closest $\mathbf b$ that does, that is, find the projection of $\hat{\mathbf b}_{t+1}$ onto $\Delta_m$. But there are two typos in line 14: the $\hat{\mathbf b}_{t+1}$ and $\mathbf{b}_{t+1}$ are reversed.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I agree with the typo that you've mentioned. About the 14th line, I wonder how the $\textbf{b}$ can be found through an optimization problem. They've written it like a summary.

Comment: You can solve that as a quadratic programming problem (quadratic objective and linear constraints).

Comment: Can we say the objective function can be written like the following (?) : $\min Z = \sqrt {{{\left( {{x_1} - {{\hat b}_{t + 1,1}}} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {{x_2} - {{\hat b}_{t + 1,2}}} \right)}^2} +  \cdots  + {{\left( {{x_n} - {{\hat b}_{t + 1,n}}} \right)}^2}} $ which in this case, the ${{\hat b}_{t + 1,i}}$ like terms are known scalars and the $x_i$ components are the weights that we are looking for. Am I true?

Comment: Yes, and for the equivalent QP you would minimize $Z^2$ (that is, omit the square root)

Comment: Thank you so much. I did so and omitted the square root since it doesn't affect the solution.